# Regex with Javascript to retrieve content from a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This seems simple but I have never done a regex so just a simple question from regex experts of JS.

```
var str = '<a href="test">luckyy1</a> born on october 21, 1986 <a href="test">sdf2</a> born on september 22, 1985 <a href="test">erere</a> born on November 23, 1984 ';
```

I got values successfully as: `luckyy1`, `sdf2`, `erere`

But I need it as `luckyy1+october+21+1986,sdf2+september+22+1985,erere+`... and so on (may be i need regex right??)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the dom? or is the html content in a string only?

Comment: yeah dom will be fine, was using jquery so far to get the $('a').each(function(index) {
     $formattedText +=  $(this).text() + $delimeter;
 });

Comment: these should be `</a>` tags, right?

Comment: yes </a>, was a mistype edited now, thanks Cek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = $("<div/>").html(str).text();
str = str.replace(/,?/g, '').replace(/born on?/g, '').split(' ').join('+')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SdtqZ/2/)

Comment: Maybe I'm being petty, but that's not the output you requested.

Answer (score 0):

While I recommend not [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/451590), this is sufficiently simple enough you should be able to do it.

`"test"\s*>(.+?\d{4})`

That will capture anything after a `"test">` tag, and end at 4 numbers (the year in your example).

Your info is space delimited in group *1*. After that, I recommend splitting on spaces to get your individual elements to play with.

[Play with the regex](http://regexr.com?31qqg).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link David, but would like to clear : href is not gonna to be test always

Comment: You need something to anchor to (a delimiter): what would a string without the `href` look like?

Comment: David, I meant  href value will not always be "test" so it sould be matched in regex as "test"

Comment: @luckycool If your tags are going to become arbitrary, I would recommend using `JQuery` like some other answers or a full-fledged HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to strip the html tags?

Give this a try:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

If you wish to get separate strings for each dom element (as your example suggests), you may transverse the DOM elements with jQuery and strip each one separately.

**EDIT:**

Something like this:

```
var $s = jQuery( the_string ); 
var result = [];
$s.each(function(i, item){ result.push( $(item).text().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"") ); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly with the markup you provided you can do something like this:

```
var values = $('<div><a href="test">luckyy1</a> born on october 21, '+
  '1986 <a href="test">sdf2</a> born on september 22, 1985 ' +
  '<a href="test">erere</a> born on November 23, 1984</div>')
  .contents()
  .map(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace('born on', '').trim();
}).get();

console.log(values); // ["luckyy1", "october 21, 1986", "sdf2", "september 22, 1985", "erere", "November 23, 1984"]
```

Only thing I changed was added a wrapping `div` to the string. You can then use `values.join('+')` to concat with a `+`, and more string replace on whitespace.

```
values.join('+').replace(/\s/g, '+'); // to make all whitespace `+`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dirty solution but somehow may help you...

```
var str = '<a href="test">luckyy1</a> born on october 21, 1986 <a href="test">sdf2</a> born on september 22, 1985 <a href="test">erere</a> born on November 23, 1984 ';

var r= /<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a> born on ([\w]*) ([\d]*), ([\d]*) <a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a> born on ([\w]*) ([\d]*), ([\d]*) <a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a> born on ([\w]*) ([\d]*), ([\d]*)/;

r.exec(str).splice(1).join('+');
```